# Why my Tomcat has no catalina.sh?

Tags: tomcat, centos

Basic info:

- OS: CentOS 7.0 x64
- Tomcat Version: 7.0.54 (installed using yum)

It begins with that I wanna debug with checking **catalina.out**. But there is nothing in the file except one line:

`tomcat-7.0.54 RPM installed`

I got some tips that   **catalina.sh** has some setting about logging. Then I found my tomcat even has no this file. In the folder `bin` there are only three files:`bootstrap.jar` `tomcat-juli.jar` `catalina-tasks.xml`

Before that I start tomcat with `systemctl start tomcat`, so I haven't notice the problem.

Is it reasonable ? What should I do if I wanna edit the setting about logging or others about startup?

Answer (score 1):

This may help you

Ref [How to install tomcat 7 on centos 7](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-7-on-centos-7-via-yum)

Log location /usr/share/tomcat/logs

The **rpm** command below will show you where all the files are.

```
rpm -ql tomcat |more
```

The **systemctl** command will given you a detailed list of the service

```
systemctl status tomcat.service  -l
```

Ref [Tomcat Logging server.xml](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Logging#Q1)

> To additionally log information about requests going to the web application, "Valves" can be configured in the **server.xml** file, as described in detail here. For example, inside the  tag:

For more information on valves in server.xml
Ref [tomcat-7.0 valve](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/valve.html)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

According to this [post](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=54207):

The yum-installed tomcat utilizes systemd, not Catalina, maybe you could add your config to this file instead: **/etc/tomcat/tomcat.conf**